Linux kernel：How to add comments in defconfig file
If i add comment at kernel defconfig. The defconfig file change to wrong format after make menuconfig.
I added the comment to mark my changes to prevent them from being overwritten by the vendor's updates.
I try to add comment with "#", will Change by "make menuconfig" below:
diff --git a/arch/arm64/configs/vendor/debug.config b/arch/arm64/configs/vendor/debug.config
index bb3b0701eba0..ef847b2c8a90 100644
--- a/arch/arm64/configs/vendor/debug.config
+++ b/arch/arm64/configs/vendor/debug.config
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
+COMMENT_START
+COMMENT_STOP
 CONFIG_ANDROID_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=y
 CONFIG_ARM_QCOM_CPUFREQ_HW=y
 CONFIG_ARM_QCOM_CPUFREQ_HW_DEBUG=y
@@ -92,9 +94,7 @@ CONFIG_QCOM_MINIDUMP_PSTORE=y
 CONFIG_QCOM_RTB=y
 CONFIG_QCOM_RTB_SEPARATE_CPUS=y
 # CONFIG_QCOM_VA_MINIDUMP is not set
-# COMMENT_START
 # CONFIG_QTI_PMIC_GLINK_CLIENT_DEBUG=y
-# COMMENT_STOP
 # CONFIG_QTI_THERMAL_MINIDUMP is not set

Question:
How to correctly add comments in defconfig?
===============
Update 08/10/2024
I found this change cause by qualcomm script config.sh
this script have function sort_config make this changes.

Surely make menuconfig changed it back to the right format, by removing the invalid lines you added?  I think you want to be providing your additional configuration in a separate file rather than by trying to edit defconfig.

Thanks, The above diff content is automatically modified by menuconfig.
The extra thing I added was not config but just comment. I think I shouldn't do this. Defconfig should not support this.
